# Array#uniq() ignoring identical hash() values?

Tags: ruby, hash, unique

Minmal testcase:

```
class C
  def hash
    3
  end  
end  
[C.new, C.new].uniq
=> [#<C:0x00000003a05098>, #<C:0x00000003a05070>]
```

According to [the 1.9.3 Array#uniq docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) it should remove duplicates. In the source it's creating a hash from the array, loops the hash, and adds each to a new array to return. This class C returns the same hash key for all objects (and you can see it's getting called by tossing a `puts` in there), but the array returned by `uniq` is not deduplicated.

Is there something more to the definition of `uniq`? It's definitely not that `==` returns true for the items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array#uniq` relies on both `hash` and `eql?` for comparison:

```
class C
  def hash
    3
  end
  def eql?( c )
    self.hash == c.hash
  end
end

[C.new, C.new].uniq # #<C:0x00000000c70498>
```

Note: if you're going to overload `eql?` then you should also overload `==`. Insert into the class definition:

```
  alias :== :eql?
```

then this evaluates as expected:

```
C.new == C.new # => true
```

Comment: More specifically it *also* relies on `eql?` for comparison.

Comment: Apparently it's both: if I define eql? to return true and don't define hash, I get two items. Defining eql? to return true and hash to return 3 gives one item as expected.

Comment: That's just how hashes work. There are an infinite number of objects but a finite number of hashes. Therefore, there are an infinite number of objects which have the same hash, even if they are not equal. Two hashes being equal doesn't tell you anything, only two hashes being different tells you that the objects cannot possibly be equal.

Comment: The override of eql? This should not be necessary -- the docs for object.c say "The <code>eql?</code> method returns <code>true</code> if +obj+ and +other+ refer to the same hash key."
-- but apparently the base class doesn't actually do that, instead just comparing object pointers -- see https://github.com/ruby/ruby/edit/trunk/object.c#L205